# Excel files with Images are being downloaded incorrectly from Amazon's S3

Tags: php, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, choropleth

I have a Web application that displays some of the user's data in a choropleth which I provide the option of exporting to an Excel file. Up until recently we had just stored the image and then the Excel file locally and provided a link to the file on the server for the user to download and it was working fine. Recently we decided to switch our system to using S3 to store the files for the user to download and ran into a problem. When the user downloads the file the image displayed isn't what should be in the file (the first image) but a box with a question mark in it (second image). Does anyone know why S3 isn't saving the images in the Excel file properly or how I can save it so that it works?  I'm using the PHPExcel library to generate the file in the first place on PHP5.4.

[image: View of Image in Web Application]

[image]